# Reading a file from a developer controlled account

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I simply want to read a Google drive spreadsheet owned by a account controlled by the developer. So I don't want my users to have to login to anything. I just need to obtain this file from hard coded credentials and read it.

It used to work very easy with drive v1 but since that doesn't seem to work anymore we are forced to go to drive v2. I haven't even found where to start.

Comment: Can you give a little more information about your architecture. The question is tagged 'android', so are you saying you want an android app to read the spreadsheet? Can it be read via a web proxy (eg on AppEngine)? Can you simply make the spreadsheet public?

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me how the data goes from the drive spreadsheet to the android device. The important thing is that it does and that on every request the data is accurate.

Comment: Well if it's me, I would create a simple AppEngine proxy which fetches the spreadsheet from Drive using a stored refresh token and then serves that as a response to a REST call from Android. That way you can keep all the Drive guff out of your Android app, keeping it clean and allowing you to (eg) serve a different spreadsheet without having to update your app.

Comment: I have never worked with AppEngine let alone AppEngine in combination with Drive so if you have any starting point for me (code snippet or tut) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you've never used AppEngine, this is probably not a good time to start. there are tons of tutorials, but all in all, it's several days of reading and getting geared up for up. You should prob look for an approach using technologies you are already familiar with. Why can't you simply make the spreadsheet public, publish it as (say) csv, then simply download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to how to use a developer controlled account is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts